# How to reset Id column content?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my SQL Server 2008 database I have a table `Inspectors`:

```
| Id | Inspector  |
| 11 | inspector1 | 
| 12 | inspector3 | 
| 13 | inspector4 | 
| 14 | inspector5 |
```

The `Id` column is the primary key and defined as auto-increment.

I need to reset the `Id` column and to make Id columns content like that:

```
| Id | Inspector  |
| 1  | inspector1 | 
| 2  | inspector3 | 
| 3  | inspector4 | 
| 4  | inspector5 |
```

Any idea how can I change Id column content above to desired `Id` content?

Comment: Are there any foreign key constraints that rely on the value of `Id` in this table?

Comment: @Igor Yes there are foreign key relation to enother tables

Comment: Don't do this to yourself. What could you possibly gain from this exercise? Identity values are just numbers and have no actual meaning. What are you going to do about gaps (which are perfectly natural).

Comment: As Sean already pointed out, identity columns aren't supposed to have any meaning other than identify a row. If you need consecutive numbers starting from one, consider the [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms186734.aspx) function in a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's possible but very strongly not recommended.** Trying to do something like this can thoroughly mess up your database integrity if you get it wrong. It would be something that would become unmaintainable as well if you thought to do this on a regular basis.

If you need to do this **one-time for a non-production database** for some testing purposes you could try the following:

- Backup your database
- Place the database in single user mode
- Remove the identity property from the field
- Add a new field with an identity property called IDnew
- Add a new field to related tables also called IDnew
- Update the IDnew column in all related tables using a join on the
  original ID to get the value
- Script the FK constraints on the child tables
- Drop the FK constraints
- Drop the ID column in the main table and the column it was associated
  to in the child tables
- Rename IDNew to ID in the parent table
- Rename the IDnew column in the child tables to the original name of
  the field in that table
- Run the scripts to create the FKS